# Save Map Annotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I just created a map view where the user can make an annotation by dropping a pin. How is it possible to save the annotation, so the user can see it when the app is closed and re-opened? Does anyone know a good tutorial for saving map annotations? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Map annotations are nothing different to regular data. The answer to this will depend on many things. For example:

1. How do you save other data in your map?
2. How many pins do you need to keep track of?

If you are only saving one pin and thus one lat and one long value, you could use NSUserDefaults. There are lots of tutorials for that around. Here's just one example: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/106311-tutorial-1-how-to-use-nsuserdefault.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I have to keep track of up to 100 pins, would you still recommend NSUserDefaults?

Comment: It could be done but I'd look at other options. An embedded sqlite database, CoreData, a text file.